# Show button if text exist

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show "Proceed" button only if user country is in the list of countries of that item using Javascript and display a message and hide proceed if it doesnt exist.
Like:
'

United States

India

And the next section has where user inputs or select their country '

Nigeria

United States

' so if User chooses like "Nigeria" which is not in available countries list i want to show them "Sorry this service is not available in Nigeria"
And if they choose like USA which is in the available countries list. I want to show them a "Proceed button" Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code.

Comment: please share code that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below JS works fine.

```js
function checkAvailability(country) {
  var countryname = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
  if (!isInArray(country))
  {
    proceed.style.display = 'none';
    error.innerText = "*Sorry this service is not available in "+ countryname;
    console.log("Sorry this service is not available in "+ countryname);
  }
  else
  {
    proceed.style.display = 'block';
    error.innerText = "";
    console.log("Available");
  }
}
var array = ["IN","US"]; // Available countries

function isInArray(value) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}
```

```html
<select id="list" onchange="checkAvailability(this.value)">
 <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
 <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
 <option value="AL">Albania</option>
 <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
 <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
 <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
 <option value="AO">Angola</option>
 <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
 <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
 <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
 <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
 <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
 <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
 <option value="AU">Australia</option>
 <option value="AT">Austria</option>
 <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
 <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
 <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
 <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
 <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
 <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
 <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
 <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
 <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
 <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
 <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
 <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
 <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
 <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
 <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
 <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
 <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
 <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
 <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
 <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
 <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
 <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
 <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
 <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
 <option value="CA">Canada</option>
 <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
 <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
 <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
 <option value="TD">Chad</option>
 <option value="CL">Chile</option>
 <option value="CN">China</option>
 <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
 <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
 <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
 <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
 <option value="CG">Congo</option>
 <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
 <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
 <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
 <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
 <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
 <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
 <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
 <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
 <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
 <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
 <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
 <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
 <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
 <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
 <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
 <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
 <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
 <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
 <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
 <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
 <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
 <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
 <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
 <option value="FI">Finland</option>
 <option value="FR">France</option>
 <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
 <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
 <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
 <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
 <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
 <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
 <option value="DE">Germany</option>
 <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
 <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
 <option value="GR">Greece</option>
 <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
 <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
 <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
 <option value="GU">Guam</option>
 <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
 <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
 <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
 <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
 <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
 <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
 <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
 <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
 <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
 <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
 <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
 <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
 <option value="IN">India</option>
 <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
 <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
 <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
 <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
 <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
 <option value="IL">Israel</option>
 <option value="IT">Italy</option>
 <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
 <option value="JP">Japan</option>
 <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
 <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
 <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
 <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
 <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
 <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
 <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
 <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
 <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
 <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
 <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
 <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
 <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
 <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
 <option value="LY">Libya</option>
 <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
 <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
 <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
 <option value="MO">Macao</option>
 <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
 <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
 <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
 <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
 <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
 <option value="ML">Mali</option>
 <option value="MT">Malta</option>
 <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
 <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
 <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
 <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
 <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
 <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
 <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
 <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
 <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
 <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
 <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
 <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
 <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
 <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
 <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
 <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
 <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
 <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
 <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
 <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
 <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
 <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
 <option value="NE">Niger</option>
 <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
 <option value="NU">Niue</option>
 <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
 <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
 <option value="NO">Norway</option>
 <option value="OM">Oman</option>
 <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
 <option value="PW">Palau</option>
 <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
 <option value="PA">Panama</option>
 <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
 <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
 <option value="PE">Peru</option>
 <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
 <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
 <option value="PL">Poland</option>
 <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
 <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
 <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
 <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
 <option value="RO">Romania</option>
 <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
 <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
 <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
 <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
 <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
 <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
 <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
 <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
 <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
 <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
 <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
 <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
 <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
 <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
 <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
 <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
 <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
 <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
 <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
 <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
 <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
 <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
 <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
 <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
 <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
 <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
 <option value="ES">Spain</option>
 <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
 <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
 <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
 <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
 <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
 <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
 <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
 <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
 <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
 <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
 <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
 <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
 <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
 <option value="TG">Togo</option>
 <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
 <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
 <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
 <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
 <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
 <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
 <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
 <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
 <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
 <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
 <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
 <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
 <option value="US">United States</option>
 <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
 <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
 <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
 <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
 <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
 <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
 <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
 <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
 <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
 <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
 <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
 <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
 <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="proceed" value="Proceed" style="display: none">
<span id="error" style="color: red;"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but how do i display a button if is Available?

Comment: @MuayyatBillah i have addressed your comment in my answer

Comment: Oh, yes saw it just now. Thanks sooo much bro

Answer (score 1):

If you want to the page to show or hide the Proceed button only from the country the user inputs in the select element you can do it like this:

```
<select id="Countries" onchange="check(this.value)">
    <option value="Select">Please select your country</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
    <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
    <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
    <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
    <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
    <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
    <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
    <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="BO">Bolivia, Plurinational State of</option>
    <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
    <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
    <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
    <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
    <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
    <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
    <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
    <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="TD">Chad</option>
    <option value="CL">Chile</option>
    <option value="CN">China</option>
    <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
    <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
    <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
    <option value="CG">Congo</option>
    <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
    <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
    <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="CI">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
    <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
    <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
    <option value="CW">Curaçao</option>
    <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
    <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
    <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
    <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
    <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
    <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
    <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
    <option value="FI">Finland</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
    <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
    <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
    <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
    <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="GR">Greece</option>
    <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
    <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
    <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="GU">Guam</option>
    <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="GG">Guernsey</option>
    <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
    <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
    <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
    <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
    <option value="HM">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
    <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
    <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
    <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="IR">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
    <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
    <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
    <option value="IM">Isle of Man</option>
    <option value="IL">Israel</option>
    <option value="IT">Italy</option>
    <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="JE">Jersey</option>
    <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
    <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
    <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
    <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
    <option value="LY">Libya</option>
    <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="MO">Macao</option>
    <option value="MK">Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
    <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
    <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
    <option value="ML">Mali</option>
    <option value="MT">Malta</option>
    <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
    <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
    <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
    <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="ME">Montenegro</option>
    <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
    <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
    <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
    <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
    <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
    <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="NE">Niger</option>
    <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="NU">Niue</option>
    <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="NO">Norway</option>
    <option value="OM">Oman</option>
    <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="PW">Palau</option>
    <option value="PS">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
    <option value="PA">Panama</option>
    <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
    <option value="PE">Peru</option>
    <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
    <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="PL">Poland</option>
    <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
    <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
    <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
    <option value="RE">Réunion</option>
    <option value="RO">Romania</option>
    <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="BL">Saint Barthélemy</option>
    <option value="SH">Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha</option>
    <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="MF">Saint Martin (French part)</option>
    <option value="PM">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
    <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
    <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
    <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
    <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="SX">Sint Maarten (Dutch part)</option>
    <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
    <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
    <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="SS">South Sudan</option>
    <option value="ES">Spain</option>
    <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
    <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
    <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
    <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
    <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
    <option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option>
    <option value="TG">Togo</option>
    <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
    <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
    <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
    <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
    <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
    <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="VE">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of</option>
    <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="VG">Virgin Islands, British</option>
    <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
    <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
    <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
<button id="proceed">Proceed</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check(countrycode) {
    if(countrycode == 'Select') {document.getElementById('proceed').style.display = ''; document.getElementById('proceed').disabled = true; return;}
    else document.getElementById('proceed').disabled = false;
    if(countrycode != 'IN' && countrycode != 'US') {
        document.getElementById('proceed').style.display = 'none';
        alert('Sorry this service is not available in ' + document.getElementById('Countries').options[document.getElementById('Countries').selectedIndex].text);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('proceed').style.display = '';
    }
}

document.getElementById('Countries').value = 'Select';
document.getElementById('proceed').disabled = true;

</script>
```

As you see here, you also need a 'Please select your country' option in your select element and it's better to set this as the selected option when the page loads. If this option is selected (which means no country is selected yet) the Proceed button is shown but is disabled and when a country is selected, if it's India or US the button is shown but if it's other an country the button hides.